# .htaccess of two WordPress installations

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two wordpress installations on my server.

The first one is on root directory and the second is on `/home` directory.

I would like to configure `.htaccess` file to:

- When an user digit `www.domain.com` redirect to `www.domain.com/home`
- When an user digit `www.domain.com/wp-admin` access to WP Admin Panel and access to the Posts and Pages on the root website.

Can I do this via `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try URL rewriting

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteRule     /wp-admin/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  /wp-admin?? [NC,L] # I'm not too sure what you want to do here...
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$            /home/      [NC,L]
```